# Failed to instantiate module dashboard due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/$injector/nomod?p0=dash

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to learn angularjs and i keep getting this error,and this is my code:

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('DashboardApp',
    [
        'dashboardService'
    ]);
```

service.js

```
var dashboardServiceModule = angular.module('dashboardService', []);
dashboardServiceModule.factory('Dashboard', function ($http) {
return {
    get_site: function () {

        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'www.google.com',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        });
    }
}
```

});

index.html

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="Dashboard">
    <input type="button" ng-model="template" value="www.google.com" ng-click="test()">
    <remote-content></remote-content>
</div>
<script>
    app.controller('dashboardCtrl', function (DashboardApp) {
        console.log("a");
    });
    angular.module('DashboardApp').directive("remoteContent", ['Dashboard', function (Dashboard) {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            template: "<p>test</p>",
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                console.log("kl;sd");
            }
        }
    }]);
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you defined an `ng-app`? Also, your `ng-controller` directive holds an undefined controller 'Dashboard', whereas it should be 'dashboardCtrl'. Change to:

```
<div ng-app="DashboardApp"> <!--If ng-app is not defined-->
    <div class="row" ng-controller="dashboardCtrl">
        <input type="button" ng-model="template" value="www.google.com" ng-click="test()">
        <remote-content></remote-content>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome. Happy to help :)